# Setting ServiceHost in VisualStudio when Working with Docker

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-container-tools

If you create a ASP.NET Core 3 Web API service it makes a file called `launchSettings.json` under "Properties".  That file has the following setting under docker:

```
"launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/index.html",
```

I am trying to find a way to set the `ServiceHost` part of this.  (Apparently this defaults to `localhost`.)  I tried adding

```
<ServiceHost>mycomputer.mydomain.net</ServiceHost>
```

to a `PropertyGroup` in my csproj file, but it had no effect (the default page loaded was still localhost).  (Though it will still work when I enter *mycomputer.mydomain.net*.

**How can I set ServiceHost for my docker run?**

NOTE: I would love an answer that includes how to do this with docker-compose as well.  (I tired moving this to docker-compose and only localhost would work (mycomputer.mydomain.net stopped working).